# Using "If" with a verb but then without that verb

Tags: grammar

So if I make a sentence such as:

> If I hover over lines, only information of that line should appear, if over any other point in the chart, nothing should happen.

*Note that I didn't use "hover" twice. Is this correct?

Comment: For the specific usage that you want, for it to be clear, you really need both words in the phrase: "hover over". I.e. "If I hover over lines... if I hover over any other point ...".  I suppose you are talking about a computer interface, in which case the above phrase can be seen as an abbreviation of the more explicit phrase "If I hover the mouse pointer over ..." so it's already been shortened to "If I hover over" with "the mouse pointer, the mouse cursor, etc." part understood by the listener.

Comment: If you begin your second phrase with "and" then you may be able to leave out "hover" and still make it clear. E.g. "If I hover over A then ..., and if over B then ...."  In my opinion, making this clear depends on having a clear structure in your sentence (if then, and if ... then), so that the 'missing' parts are easy to understand by the reader. Go to ELL as suggested above for more precise explanations about this.

Comment: The technical word for leaving stuff out like this is called 'elision' and used as a verb, it is 'elide' (e.g. sometimes in English one may elide the subject). Maybe you will get some more information about this topic if you look for this keyword. I'm not sure if it makes sense to talk about elision as 'correct' though. I would think of it as OK or not OK. If you leave out too much, and the message is lost, then that's not OK. If you leave out something, but the message is still clear, then that's OK even if someone can argue that it's "incorrect".

Comment: We don't do proofreading on this site. Can you please edit your question to make it clear which part of your sentence you're unsure about, and which aspect of English is involved? *"If" with a verb but then without that verb* is not precise enough. Are you unsure about the **tense**, **conjunction**, **punctuation** or **article usage**, for instance?